# move element after certain element + two `<br>`

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which works fine, however I wanted to know if there is a better way to add the `<br>'s`

Is there a better more efficient way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
$('#pt656').after($("input[name='btnaddtocart']"));
$('#pt656').after('<br><br>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use the `<br>` at all, but instead use CSS to style your content and introduce block-level display and margins as desired. More details here: http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#badBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add space between elements with CSS. Following adds 20px space between elements `#pt656` and `btnaddtocart`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
  $('#pt656').after($("input[name='btnaddtocart']").css('margin-top', '20px'));
</script>
```